# bootstrap navbar footer is not working properly when its shrink to mobile size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

when i responsive my page footer is like this.. is this correct or not .
if its is not then tell what iam doing mistake and what is the proper solution.`enter code here`

```
            <div class="row" id="social">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4" id="copyrights">
                    <h6> Copyright &copy; 2016 reversed  </h6>
                </div><!--col-sm-2-->


                <!--
                <div class="col-sm-4" id="navigation" >



                </div><!--sm-2-->
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-push-6 social-circle" >


                      <ul class="social-network social-circle ">
                    <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1px"></i></a></li>

                    <li><a href="#" class="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>

                </ul>   
                </div>
                </div>  
            </div>

        </div> <!--end -->
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?